# netbeans IDE 8.1 "Unable to connect to the Plugin Portal because of Connection reset"

Tags: netbeans, java-8, network-connection

Can't install any plugin in netbeans ide 8.1.

I get the following error:

> Unable to connect to the Plugin Portal because of Connection reset
>
> Check your proxy settings or try again later. The server may be unavailable at the moment. You may also want to make sure that your
> firewall is not blocking network traffic.

Or when run Check for updates:

> Unable to connect to the Plugin Portal because of Connection reset

Already tried:

1. Turn off the fire wall
2. Add the option "-J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" to the netbeans_default_options in "\NetBeans 8.1\etc\netbeans.conf"
3. Run netbeans as System Administrator

What can i do?
Please help

Comment: The plugin portal has had several problems lately. It's nothing you can do

Answer (score 4):

Click on `Tools -> Options`  in the `General` tab select the `No Proxy` radio button if you are not using any `Proxy Settings` for your Computer. This might be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Goto to `Tools -> Plugins -> Settings`

Edit the link of Plugin Portal to the correct URL as per your Netbeans installation from the following link:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NETBEANS/Where+to+download+plugins+for+NetBeans+10.0+and+earlier

For Netbeans 8.1 it is: http://plugins.archive.librebeans.org/catalogue/8.1/catalog.xml

Answer (score 0):

Download the plugin manually from netbeans [plugin portal](https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/)  and install it directly on your IDE. This solved my issue